# How to hide a div with it's id in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Here i want to hide a div with id,is it possible in angularJS.I know it is possible to hide anything with `ng-hide` or `ng-show`.but i dont know how to hide a div with it's id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use good old jquery to do that, but it's really preferable to avoid modifying the dom directly like that.

Using a scope variable give far more flexibility than modifying style attributes directly.

Use ng-if if you don't want the markup in the dom.

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: $( "#target" ).hide();

Comment: Or simply `document.getElementById('target').style.display = 'none'`